# Created two iPhone Apps and integrated Facebook SDK's and both apps have same fbApp-Id

Tags: iphone

New to iPhone Facebook Integration, Problem is i have developed two apps and integrated Facebook sdk in two apps , i had run the two apps in device with different provisions , and both are installed in iPhone , I have given same App - Id in info.plist of both the apps problem is

if suppose Apps A and B are there , So in App 'A' if i click the login button for facebook ,it opens the facebook app in my iphone and after clicking the okay it returns back to App  'B' and show in that app 'B' is logged-in into face book , and remanning vice versa.

**MAIN Requirement:**

My main feature is i have two A and B integrated Facebook in both the Apps , if logged in to facebook in 'A' it should show that both A and B are logged - in,

Please help me .

Thanks ,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we can give same appid for different applications, but in login screen, that app name is showing for both apps, that is not a problem.

plz make sure to include below code in appdelegate.m :

facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"481018011908421"];

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 
    {

        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        NSLog(@"FBAccessTokenKey = %@~~~~ FBExpirationDateKey = %@",facebook.accessToken,facebook.expirationDate);


    }
```

and i think appid is not required in info.plist and need to give in appdelegate.